# What Pin Pad for Raspberry Pi POS with no payments involved?

Tags: keyboards, raspberry-pi

I’m developing kind of a POS system for my school cafe. It doesn’t need to work with payments, instead it works with the member system. The system will be running in Raspberry Pi and Python, connecting to the member system API.

When a customer buys something, they enter their member number and that should go to a database with the amount they purchased.

I want the customers to enter their number in a pin pad; however, I don’t know what pin pad I should use. I have read on Verifone and Ingenico pin pads but they require an encryption key by a merchant, but since we won’t be working with payments, security is not that essential.

I thought about using keypads, but I can’t find one that includes a mini screen and is rugged enough for this type of application. I appreciate any suggestions on the matter, or if I’m better off going with a touchscreen for the Pi.

Thank you!

Comment: Would a touchscreen be acceptable instead of a physical pin pad?

Comment: Yes, I think a touchscreen would be a potential solution. Maybe a small touchscreen that the Pi would mount behind of, and run a web page in kiosk mode to gather the member numbers.

Comment: In that case, a resistive touch screen may be a good choice. If food is going to be handled near the screen it will still register touches for people wearing gloves or if some kind of substance is on people's hands or the screen. Capacitive screens are nicer to use for gestures and dragging, but don't work with some kinds of gloves or can get confused if there is water on the screen.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will research those types of screens for the kitchen area!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options for you:

- [Jelly Comb USB Keypad](https://amzn.to/32OKlK5)
- [Adafruit 3x4 Phone-style Matrix Keypad](https://amzn.to/3asnmH5)
- [DEVMO 2PCS 4 x 4 Matrix Array](https://amzn.to/2TmufnC)
- [Adafruit Membrane 3x4 Matrix Keypad + Extras [ADA419]](https://amzn.to/2xbkY9w)
- [Official Raspberry Pi 7" Touch Screen Display](https://amzn.to/2wpwptL)

Comment: Thank you for the ideas! Might be able to combine a keypad of those with some small display!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a membrane 3x4 keypad from adafruit, I Just bought one and the keys are really easy to press and the pinout is easy to understand.